# Why does app crash at NSData getBytes?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nsdata

NSData is extended to determine the file type:

```
extension NSData {
    var dataType: String? {

        // Ensure data length is at least 1 byte
        guard self.length > 0 else { return nil }

        // Get first byte
        var c = [UInt8](count: 1, repeatedValue: 0)
        self.getBytes(&c, length: 1)

        // Identify data type
        switch (c[0]) {
        case 0xFF:
            return "jpg"
        case 0x89:
            return "png"
        case 0x47:
            return "gif"
        case 0x49, 0x4D:
            return "tiff"
        default:
            return nil //unknown
        }
    }
}
```

The method above is called on a `NSData` object from image data that is fetched from a server.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {

    do {
        // Fetch image synchronously from server
        let query = PFQuery(className: <...>)
        let result = try query.getFirstObject()

        guard
            let imageObject = result.objectForKey(<...>) as? PFFile,
            let imageData = try? imageObject.getData(),
            let image = imageData.dataType == "gif" ? UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData(imageData) : UIImage(data: imageData)
        else {
            return
        }

        <...>

    } catch (let error as NSError) {
        <...>
    }
}
```

However the app very rarely crashes at line `self.getBytes`:

[image]

What is the reason for this?

The buffer of getBytes is `&c`, an `UnsafeMutablePointer` - do I have to take any special memory considerations because of that?

### Update

The crashes still occur with the following variation of the code:

```
// Get first byte
var c: UInt8 = 0;
self.getBytes(&c, length: 1)
```

### Update

The crashes still occur with the following variation of the code:

```
// Get first byte
var c = [UInt8](count: 1, repeatedValue: 0)
c.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
    buffer in
    getBytes(buffer.baseAddress, length: 1)
}

guard c.indices.contains(0) else { return nil }
```

I got the following crash and included the whole thread, maybe someone can spot a hint:

```
Thread 18 Crashed:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib             0x21a8e198 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$CortexA9 + 92
1   Foundation                           0x22512923 __34-[_NSDispatchData getBytes:range:]_block_invoke + 176
2   libdispatch.dylib                    0x218d238d _dispatch_data_apply + 82
3   libdispatch.dylib                    0x218d4a51 dispatch_data_apply + 26
4   Foundation                           0x22512865 -[_NSDispatchData getBytes:range:] + 86
5   Foundation                           0x2267730b -[_NSDispatchData getBytes:length:] + 24
6   MyAppName                               0x00079ba0 partial apply forwarder for (extension in MyAppName):__ObjC.NSData.(dataType.getter : Swift.String?).(closure #1) (NSData+Extension.swift:54)
7   MyAppName                               0x00079c14 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@inout Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@unowned (), @error @owned Swift.ErrorType) to @callee_owned (@inout Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out (), @error @owned Swift.ErrorType) (NSData+Extension.swift:0)
8   MyAppName                               0x00079cb8 generic specialization <Swift.UInt8, ()> of Swift.Array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer <A> ((inout Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A>) throws -> A1) throws -> A1 (NSData+Extension.swift:0)
9   MyAppName                               0x00079a70 (extension in MyAppName):__ObjC.NSData.dataType.getter : Swift.String? (NSData+Extension.swift:55)
10  MyAppName                               0x00079948 @objc (extension in MyAppName):__ObjC.NSData.dataType.getter : Swift.String? (NSData+Extension.swift:0)
11  MyAppName                               0x000d2264 MyAppName.DataManager.(fetchImagesFromServer (MyAppName.ImageSet) -> ()).(closure #1) (DataManager.swift:1214)
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x218cd823 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x218dc5e9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1558
14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x218dbfcd _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x21a91b29 _pthread_wqthread + 1022
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x21a91718 start_wqthread + 6
```

### Update

The crashes still occur with the following variation of the code:

```
// Get first byte
var c = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(1)
defer { c.dealloc(1) }
self.getBytes(c, length: 1)    

switch (c[0]) { ...
```

Comment: You should check if the NSData object contains at least one byte. Otherwise I don't see why that method should crash.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I will add a `guard self.length > 0 else { return nil }` before the `getBytes` statement. Because this happens very rarely I will keep this post updated...

Comment: @MartinR Do I also have to test for `self != nil` before testing for `length`? `self` can't be nil, can it?

Comment: Unfortunately the app still crashes sometimes at `self.getBytes(&c, length: 1)` despite `guard self.length > 0 else { return nil }`.

Comment: What's the exception when it crashes?

Comment: @jtbandes I only have the crash log from the live app, as posted above. It crashes very rarely, maybe in 1 per mill sessions, so I cannot reproduce the crash locally.

Comment: Have you run it under the memory sanitizer?

Comment: @robmayoff No, how would I do that?

Comment: Watch this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/413/

Comment: Enabled address sanitizer but it didn't report anything. However I will try a new implementation: `var c = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(1)`, `defer { c.dealloc(1) }`, `self.getBytes(c, length: 1)`.

Comment: Crash still happens, I will request a TSI with Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of an Apple engineer (via a TSI ticket) the issue was finally identified.
All code permutations above for reading the first byte are valid and working.

The issue was that the `NSData` object was created when a file was fetched from a server using the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) which stores the data in a temporary file with file protection key `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`.

The file protection key allows reading data of the `NSData` object only after the user unlocks the device once after reboot. Although the data is not readable before unlocking, the `NSData` object can be created and even the `NSData.length` property is accessible. However, attempting to read the data would throw an exception.

I changed the code and added a check if the protected data is available before attempting to read it with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().protectedDataAvailable`.

You may wonder why a file was fetched by the app before the device was even unlocked. The app was started by a remote user notification. That explains why the crash happened so rarely.

Learned 2 things:

- Always check your file protection key
- Apple technical support gave a super in-depth explanation and is worth the money

Answer (score 2):

A Swift array is more like a C++ `std::vector` than a C array: it has other contents besides the array elements. You can't get a pointer to the first element using `&c`. You need to ask the array for a pointer to its elements, like this:

```
var c = [UInt8](count: 1, repeatedValue: 0)
c.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { buffer in
    getBytes(buffer.baseAddress, length: 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, could you explain a bit how this helps and what the actual issue seems to be?

Comment: So I found an explanation for `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47085. Specifically eskimo says: "Swift guarantees that pointers you generate this way [with `&c`] will remain valid for the duration of the function call." I assume that `getBuffer` does not call the address only once so I have to access the unsafe pointer in the close as you suggested. I'll try that out and post updates here.

Comment: I don't know what `getBuffer` is.

Comment: But according to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17 ("Mutable Pointers"), `self.getBytes(&c, length: 1)` passes the address of the array, as in the example `takesAMutablePointer(&a)` given there.

Comment: I know, but I've had trouble with it just like Manuel, and I found that `withUnsafeBufferPointer` (or the mutable version) always works.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for your detailed answer, which I assume would solve my question regarding the array. However I marked Julien's answer as accepted because he pointed out that an array is not even needed in my case. Thank again

Comment: @robmayoff I am trying your suggestion now since with Julien's suggestion the app crashed again at `getBytes` :(

Comment: @robmayoff I also had a crash with your suggestion. I included the complete crashed thread in my question above, maybe you can see anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case, it seems overkill to use an array, though. Why not just do:

```
var c: UInt8 = 0;

self.getBytes(&c, length: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that an array it not even needed here.

Comment: So it turned out that also with your given solution the app crashes again at `getBytes` with the same crash log stack. Very confusing. I will try rob's suggestion.

Comment: If this still crashes, the problem is not here but more likely with your data content (released/deallocated before use?).

Comment: How can there be a data problem when I try to determine the first byte? Shouldn.t that work regardless of the data? Or could it have something to do with the fact that the function is called from a background thread?

Comment: It's hard to say because we have no clue here where you data comes from and how you pass it around before accessing it but the `getBytes()` code is correct and should not crash if the data's buffer is good.

Comment: I've added the calling code in the question. I was thinking that maybe it is caused by just one of many images on the server because the function fetches many different image from cloud. On the other hand I believe data is data and there is no "wrong" data, so why would it make any difference...

Comment: The problem is if the underlying buffer has been deallocated, the memory region the NSData instance points to (or the instance itself) is no longer valid and trying to read it can give you random data (at best) or crash (at worst)

Comment: Could a `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` cause the memory to be deallocated or the pointer to change? That would explain why the crash happens so rarely because the event and the buffer reading would have to occur almost at the same time. On the other hand I wouldn't know what to do about it if that was the case.